# combine list of lists in python (similar to string.join but as a list comprehension?)

Tags: python, list

If you had a long list of lists in the format `[['A',1,2],['B',3,4]]` and you wanted to combine it into `['A, 1, 2', 'B, 3, 4']` is there a easy list comprehension way to do so?

I do it like this:

```
this_list = [['A',1,2],['B',3,4]]
final = list()
for x in this_list:
     final.append(', '.join([str(x) for x in x]))
```

But is this possible to be done as a one-liner?

Thanks for the answers. I like the map() based one. I have a followup question - if the sublists were instead of the format `['A',0.111,0.123456]` would it be possible to include a string formatting section in the list comprehension to truncate such as to get out `'A, 0.1, 0.12'`

Once again with my ugly code it would be like:

```
this_list = [['A',0.111,0.12345],['B',0.1,0.2]]
final = list()
for x in this_list:
    x = '{}, {:.1f}, {:.2f}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2])
    final.append(x)
```

I solved my own question:

```
values = ['{}, {:.2f}, {:.3f}'.format(c,i,f) for c,i,f in values]
```

Comment: @mgilson It's not a flat list.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- I'm confused.  OP has a list of lists, and wants a flat list.  No?

Comment: no, it's 2 strings in his example

Comment: Ohh, so it is.  Alright, *removes foot from mouth (fingers?)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> lis = [['A',1,2],['B',3,4]]
>>> [', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in lis ]
['A, 1, 2', 'B, 3, 4']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with `str.join`:

```
>>> lst = [['A',1,2],['B',3,4]]
>>> [", ".join([str(y) for y in x]) for x in lst]
['A, 1, 2', 'B, 3, 4']
>>>
```

Comment: @alko Actually for large lists they are recommended. But for small lists, yes they can be dropped.

Comment: @alko - Yea.  Here is a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451).

Comment: Just found topic myself. I wasn't aware of that 2-pass behaviour of join, thanks, @AshwiniChaudhary and @iCodez!

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [['A',1,2],['B',3,4],['A',0.111,0.123456]]

print    [', '.join(map(str,sli)) for sli in li]


def func(x):
    try:
        return str(int(str(x)))
    except:
        try:
            return '%.2f' % float(str(x))
        except:
            return str(x)

print map(lambda subli: ', '.join(map(func,subli)) , li)
```

return

```
['A, 1, 2', 'B, 3, 4', 'A, 0.111, 0.123456']
['A, 1, 2', 'B, 3, 4', 'A, 0.11, 0.12']
```